# Why is data from one event being overwritten by another event?

Tags: jquery

I have got a two toggle buttons.

On click of the each toggle button I am displaying different data.

The issue I am facing is that on click of the second toggle button, the first toggle button's data is being overridden with the second toggle button's data.

https://jsfiddle.net/gx4nj1Lg/1/

some part of my code

```
  jQuery('#toggle-view li').click(function() {
        jQuery('div.p').html("");

        var clcikedon = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        if (clcikedon === 'first') {
             var itemshtml = '<table class="table table-striped">';
            for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
                itemshtml += ' <tr>\
            <td>' + firstdata[i].date + '</td>\
            <td>' + firstdata[i].name + '</td>\
            </tr>'
            }
             itemshtml += '</table>';
        }
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
jQuery('div.panel').html(itemshtml);
```

It sets the html of all div's with a class of panel. Which is the div in both the first and second panels.

Use the jQuery find function to search within a specific element:

```
jQuery(this).find('div.panel').html(itemshtml);
```

Is there a reason you wouldn't set the html in both panels before the clicks on the dropdowns? The the dropdowns just have to open and close.

take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gx4nj1Lg/4/